# I can’t close a pop-up on the flipkart web-site

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to learn Selenium , i used flipkart site to automate , but when i redirect to flipkart i cant able to close a pop up

I used the 'x' button by its xpath & classname but its not working
[img][https://i.ibb.co/7bhDJYw/Screenshot-2022-11-29-at-10-31-19-AM.png[/img]](https://i.ibb.co/7bhDJYw/Screenshot-2022-11-29-at-10-31-19-AM.png%5B/img%5D)

```
package ui;


import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Popup {
    public static String browser = "Firefox";
    public static FirefoxDriver driver;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        if (browser.equals("Firefox")) {

            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browser.equals("Chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (browser.equals("Edge")) {
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();

            EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");

//        Thread.sleep(5000);
       // driver.findElement(By.className("_2KpZ6l _2doB4z")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
//        Alert alert = (Alert) driver.switchTo().alert();
//        alert.dismiss();

    }
}
```

this is the code i tried

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
driver.findElement(By.className("_2KpZ6l _2doB4z")).click();
```

do this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'✕')]")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._2KpZ6l._2doB4z")).click();
```

Comment: Third line of code above has an extra character sequence `]")` that should presumably be removed.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've removed that.

Comment: Hey tried this , but still not working , just idle at the popup